# Symfony2, validation on getters, show error on form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, getter

I have a problem with errors using Symfony2 FormComponent.

I've validation for getters in bundle:

```yml
getters:
    someGetter:
        - MyOwnValidator: { message: "Fail"}
```

After that, I want to validate form and show errors:

```
{{form_errors(form)}}
```

returns to me bunch of errors (including error for someGetter), but

```
{{form_errors(form.someGetter)}}
```

doesn't return anything.

Any ideas?

### UPDATE

I've found the solution. Field, for which I implemented validation (someGetter) is a collection type without `'error_bubbling' => 'false'` option.

When I added error_bubbling, everything works fine.

Comment: If you found the solution please post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

Other options to have the getters error is with http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#error-mapping and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#error-bubbling

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Field, for which I implemented validation (someGetter) is a collection type without 'error_bubbling' => 'false' option.

When I added error_bubbling, everything works fine.

---

Answer extracted from updated question.