# Symfony2 getter validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I need to validate `DateTime` values for a booking system for hostels and hotels. For that, I need getter validation. I implemented `isArrivalDateValid()` method that return false (for testing purposes).

When i try to run the method in twig with form_errors(form.ArrivalDateValid), i keep getting `ArrivalDateValid` does not exist although Symfony knows its a method.

The same problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719970/symfony2-validation-on-getters-show-error-on-form)

but he solved it with `error_bubbling` but mine isn't, no matter if `error_bubbling` is true or false; I have a feeling that this is a basic problem but for the last hour, i cannot solve no matter what i do.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the validation.yml...

```
Hotel\RezervacijaBundle\Entity\Rezervacija:
    properties:
        Ime :
            - NotBlank : { message : "Ime je obavezno" }
        Prezime :
            - NotBlank: { message: "Prezime je obavezno" }
        Email :
            - NotBlank : { message: "E-mail je obavezan" }
            - Email : { message: "E-mail mora biti ispravan" }
    getters:
        ArrivalDateValid :
            - "False" : { message "Vrijeme dolaska ne može biti u prošlosti" }
```

Comment: could you show validation config?

Answer (score 0):

When using YAML, be sure to surround True with quotes ('True') or else YAML will convert this into a true Boolean value.

Please check out at http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/True.html

and you can check this reference for show getters messages http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#error-bubbling and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#error-mapping